# Golang unset Struct Field

Tags: json, go, struct, marshalling

In Golang, I have below Struct with three fields

```
type Person struct {
   name string
   age  int
   rank int
}
```

For Processing, I need a rank field, but for output, I want to exclude the rank field from struct as I am directly passing above struct to JSON encoder to throw a response.

Is there any way by which I can unset rank field from Struct?

Comment: Just add a fied tag `json:"-"`. Note that this struct is as a whole is not going to be parsed by `encoding/json` as long as you don't export fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To unset a field, assign its zero value to it, like:

```
var p Person
p.rank = 0
```

Also know that if you want to use `Person` to work with JSON, you have to export the fields, unexported fields are not processed by the `encoding/json` package, so change `Person` to:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    rank int
}
```

This alone will make `rank` left out from JSON processing, as it is unexported.

If you need to export the `rank` field too, then use the `json:"-"` tag value to exclude an exported field from JSON processing:

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
    Rank int `json:"-"`
}
```

Comment: Seems, reliable way with field of any type(not just int) would be p.rank=new(Person).rank

Comment: @Uvelichitel But that may be really inefficient, compared to what is needed.

Comment: @Uvelichitel You could also do it with reflection if your goal is to expend resources. Go is a type-safe language, you know when you're writing the code what each field's type is, there's no reason to use extra code to figure out the zero value at runtime.